# I am trying to use multiple mq for responsive styling

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

On my website I am trying to use media quieres to specify a mobile size, tablet size, and desktop size. Well, when I make edits to the tablet it applies those edits to the whole page instead of just when its sized to a tablet. What can I do to stop this and continue with the responsive design.

```
    @media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
    nav{
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 50px;
    }
    nav > ul {
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
        list-style: none;
    }


    nav > ul > li, nav > ul > li > a {
        line-height: 20px;
        display: list-item;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    .hamburger {
        padding: 20px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
 /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 

    nav{
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;

    }
    nav > ul {
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
        list-style: none;
    }
    nav > ul > li, nav > ul > li > a {
        line-height: 0px;
        display: list-item;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .hamburger {
        padding: 20px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your media queries need to be more precise or consistent, `min-width:320px` targets everything 320 and up and `max-width: 768px` targets everything from 768 and down. You could specify a range instead of only max or only min, depending on how your site is setup

Comment: It doesn't work... If i change the mobile version to what you provided and all my css styles on my website were removed.

Comment: I am just telling you how media queries work, you will need to restructure it so it works better. Go from small to large or large to small but don't mix them or it will get really confusing or specify ranges only so it does not affect other queries. Your issue right now is that you are properly structuring the css to work with media query, take time to figure it out and you will get what you want

Comment: Ok thank you, for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this query sequentially.** Hope that it would be help.

```
/* Large screen desktop */
@media (min-width: 1170px) and (max-width: 1365px){

}

/* Normal desktop :992px. */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1169px) {

}


/* Tablet desktop :768px. */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* small mobile :320px. */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Large Mobile :480px. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

}
```

Comment: I tried this and when I changed it to the code you provided all my css code styles were removed from the website and won't show unless I go back to what it was originally.

Answer (score 0):

To get responsive images you have a few options.

Designate by general size using `scrset`:

Small: Under 600 px aimed at mobile users

Medium: Between 600 px-900 px aimed at midsized computer and tablets

Large: Over 900 px aimed at desktop monitors.

`Scrset` can also be used to designate percentages of screen space. For example, if you want the image to cover the full width of the screen you would use `100%`. Then the browser will adjust the image to 100% width for the screen size of the visitor, regardless of the device.

You can also use the  tag and the auto option for the size parameters. Such as: `<img> width=auto height=auto`. This will use client information to size the image.

Thirdly, while not as widely accepted, you can use `client_hints=true` along with the auto size option to get responsive images.  This feature is fully supported by Chrome, not yet by other popular browsers.